# Where do I store project data in Unity?

Tags: unity

In Unity the PhysicsManager has project data. It exists across scenes but its data is unique to each project. If it make my own CustomManager, where/how to I store its data so that it's associated with the project, not a particular scene.

Most of the examples show storing data in properties in components on GameObjects but the PhysicsManager is not a component of a GameObject as far as I can tell. I want my custom manager to do whatever PhysicsManager is doing to store its data.

Any examples, pointers, links to articles?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of data you have to store [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) should be perfect for that. If player prefs is not enough or does not suits your needs you can store project custom data in a text file (personally i place it in resources but it could be anywhere) and read it when needed

for ex : i made a plugin for unity to define different sizes atlases path, and everything is stored in a textfile where i have some JSON arrays, and when i load my scene i read my file and forget about it